# Agile methodology causing fragmented design

Tags: agile

How do you prevent agile methodology with monthly sprints/iterations causing a fragmented design. For ex. take the case of design of Manhattan Streets vs Design of Boston streets. The blueprints for Manhattan Streets were designed as a whole resulting in easy manoeverability and driving. Boston streets were designed in a piece meal approach and its a nightmare getting around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agile development is not a mandate to throw away over-arching design. It makes a lot of sense to plan 'the big picture' - what the responsibilities of your major components are, and how they will interact, for example. In my own team, I find a reasonable compromise is to agree a broad public API up front, but defer detailed implementation decisions where possible. This allows individual developers the freedom to modify the design as the implementation evolves, while also gaining the benefit of hashing out different approaches at the design level, when changes are much cheaper. Modularity is also key - keep components specific in function and as decoupled from one another as possible. This minimises your overheads when you find you need to make changes to your implementation, and should increase the chances that individual components you write remain useful.

Answer (score 10):

Streets are a bad analogy to use for software.  Streets cannot be easily moved, rerouted, or changed without *significant* effort.  Well-written software is an composition of orthogonal components that are easily reorganized and modified as needed.

The reason that agile development works is that both the developers and the software itself are agile.  The developers respond quickly to change and the software they write is written in a manner that makes it responsive to change as well.

Answer (score 6):

Refactor, refactor, refactor.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a design phase that decides on the Streets. What buildings get built is determined in each phase.

I think that there is a tendency to do too little design/architecture in scrum projects. You can do constant refactoring but that can be alot of work, if something has not been designed. You can get into the same problem if there is an error in the design.

Answer (score 1):

Use of [SOLID principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) would result in code which is loosely coupled & highly cohesive.

**Remember design is the king.**

IMHO analogies of software components with Buildings, Streets are just illogical. None of this is even remotely similar to software development or software design.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a risk that Agile users will suggest adjusting the principals of agile to the situation at hand, however when this subsequently fails this leaves those who support the move to Agile open to criticism because Agile is not being adopted fully.

Fragmented design is a continuous risk with Agile because there is no value on architecture. What is needed is a methodology that uses the advantageous aspects of Agile such as Continuous Delivery but solves problems like the un-scalability of Agile. A possible approach is [The Game of Thrones Methodology](http://digitalanimal.com/blog/slaying-the-agile-dragon-the-game-of-thrones-methodology/) which does just this.

Answer (score 0):

"Agile methodology" (and I assume you mean SCRUM, here) has little to do with the architecture of your design; the architecture being a property of the software or the system your creating (in the UML world you would maybe call it "artefacts").

"Agile" does not tell you anything about what kind of software you write, it can be used for any and all types of software or even easily for projects that have nothing to do with software at all.

So if you have the feeling that there is a bad software architecture in your agile project(s), then you should be looking around at what the actual cause is. Only because you are agile does not mean that everybody does what he wants without a plan, or that you need no documentation at all. While you won't specifiy every class down to the bit level before starting your work, you still will want a high-level architecture written down, even before the first sprint. Depending on your team size and constituency, you could imagine using your first sprint to even *create* your architecture.